# Google Apps Gmail missing import from other email service

Tags: gmail, google, google-workspace

My instance of Google Apps Gmail is missing import from other email service as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: missing import]

I was expecting what I get below with normal/personal Gmail:

[image: with normal/personal Gmail]

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Apps accounts get new features on a delayed time basis - quite possibly they are meant for enterprise deployments where stability is paramount.

You'll get the import feature in due course.